# Lock screen timed lockout

Tags: screen-lock

Is it possible to configure the Mac lock screen to refuse to accept login attempts for a certain amount of time after the lock screen is activated?

Comment: Eh, I think not. Why would you want that?

Comment: As an extra security precaution for corporate machines (I'm in infosec).

Comment: Ok, it's a great thought but I have no idea how that would be possible. Maybe just set a stronger password?